# How to check if someone is currently on the website (online) using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a website with chat etc. The problem is I cannot correctly define if someone is currently on the website which cause I cannot set their activity.

I wrote a function which is invoked by the body tag in HTML file `<body onload="changeStatus(true)" onunload="changeStatus(false)">` but as I said it seems not to work.

When the status of the first users sets to the online value, the second one immediately changes to offline. When I try to type something in the input on the website it also changes the status to offline, it doesn't matter who is typing.

I am currently thinking of writing this part in PHP just using the session, but maybe someone knows how to do this in JS?

```js
function changeStatus(event) {
  if (event) {
    db.ref("status/" + username + "/" + receiver).set({
      act: "online"
    });
  } else {
    db.ref("status/" + username + "/" + receiver).set({
      act: "offline"
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to build a presence system, in which case I recommend checking out the Firebase documentation on [managing presence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-presence), [how `onDisconnect` works](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#how-ondisconnect-works), [detecting connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) and the [sample presence app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to determine if the page has loaded? If so then a simple jquery document load on will do that

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

```js
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( window ).on( "load", function() {
        console.log( "window loaded" );
    });
//or
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
    </script>
```

if your trying to capture if the user is on the page then mouse over or mouse click might be better

https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

https://api.jquery.com/click/

I hope this helps